# How to convert 0x00 to 0b00000?

Tags: python

This is from the document :  (byte to hex if I am correct)

```
0x00 -> 0b00000000

lim1: Bit0 = 0  (last index)
lim2: Bit1 = 0  (second last index)
lim3: Bit2 = 0  (third last index)
```

But when I did this :

```
binascii.unhexlify('00')
```

I got this

```
b'\x00'
```

So I dont know if I convert hex to byte correctly.

Comment: `int(a, 16)` will return an integer value, that you can use to check the bits.

Comment: It is not clear what `"0x01 -> 0b00000000"` means. You need to print this string? Is 0x01 a number literal, or a string (including that 0x)? Etc... Please add clarifications as exactly what the input format is and the output (format).

Comment: `'0b{:08b}'.format(int(s, 16))`

Comment: 0x00 is the same number as 0b00000, are you aware of that? Point is, that in that light, your question title doesn't make any sense. Please start with what you have, as a [mcve]. Then, explain what you want the resulting behaviour to be, in a way that can be verified.

Comment: Your title says "how do I convert zero to zero", but your code converts the *string* `'00'`to zero. It doesn't matter how you write a number, it's still the same number.

Comment: Unless the digits are import, it's correct